# How to get file from a filesystem and pass it to my transformation using write batcher?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I need to fetch a json document from a filesystem using write batcher and pass it to my transformation through dmsdk. How can I do this? How can I add file to batcher?

Answer (score 0):

After configuring the WriteBatcher using the withTransform() fluent, you can pass in a FileInputStream on each file as follows:

```
writeBatcher.add("/path/filename.json", new InputStreamHandle(fileInputStream));
```

For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/datamovement/WriteBatcher.html#withTransform-com.marklogic.client.document.ServerTransform-

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/io/InputStreamHandle.html#InputStreamHandle-java.io.InputStream-

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/datamovement/WriteBatcher.html#add-java.lang.String-com.marklogic.client.io.marker.AbstractWriteHandle-